# xslt reading from xml separate elements, not working

Tags: xml, object, xslt

I got an xml like this:

```html
<movies>
 <!-- 1 -->
    <movie>      
        <movieID>0108052</movieID>     
        <title>Schindler's List</title>
        <director>Steven Spielberg</director>  
        <year>1993</year>
        <genre>Biography, </genre>
  <genre>Drama, </genre>
  <genre>History</genre>
  <link>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108052/</link>
    </movie>
 <!-- 2 -->
    <movie>      
        <movieID>0914798</movieID>     
        <title>The Boy in the Striped Pajamas</title>
        <director>Mark Herman</director>  
        <year>2008</year>
        <genre>Biography, </genre>
  <genre>Drama, </genre>
  <genre>History</genre>
  <link>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0914798/</link>  
    </movie>
</movies>
```

Now it should read it and output it like this: (different movie to show variety)

```html
<tr bgcolor="#3D9999">
  <td><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091369/" target="_blank">Labyrinth</a>
  </td>
  <td>Jim Henson</td>
  <td>1986</td>
  <td>Adventure, Family, Fantasy</td>
  <td>0091369</td>
</tr>
```

But instead i am getting this:

```
  <td>Adventure, </td>
```

MY xslt looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <!-- Background image -->
    <body background="bgimage.jpg">
      <h2 style="color:#47B2B2">My Movie Collection</h2>
      <h3 style="color:#47B2B2">Movies After 2005:</h3>
      <!-- set border, color, and padding Movies after 2005-->
      <table border="1" bgcolor="#0A1A1A" cellpadding="5">
        <tr bgcolor="#1F4C4C">
          <!-- Set order -->
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Director</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Genre</th>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
          <!-- Sort by title -->
          <xsl:sort select="title" />
          <xsl:if test="year>=2005">
            <tr bgcolor="#3D9999">
              <td>
                <!-- Look for link, target to blank, the link text is the tittle pulled from xml -->
                <a href="{link}" target="_blank">
                  <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="director" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="year" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="genre" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="movieID" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Line 47 handles how it should read it, but well it does not work it only reads the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what `xsl:value-of` does in this context. The quick solution is to swap out

```
<xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
```

for

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="genre"/>
```

Assuming you don't have a template that will handle the 'genre' element, this will use XSLT's built in template and output just the text. If that fails, you can always fall back on

```
<xsl:for-each select="genre">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Incidentally, while it might make your solution to this a little easier, having the separating comma included in the data is really poor XML design. It makes it much harder to query what films have a given genre for example, if you have to detect both 'genre' and 'genre, '. If the source data is ever changed to not include the comma, you can do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="genre">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, if you ever upgrade to XSLT 2.0, you can just do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="genre" separator=", "/>
```

which WILL output all genre elements, with the given separator.

Comment: This is a perfect explanation, thank you. I know its poor xml design, but the professor asked for it. He says jump, I ask how high.